# N-lines with the phrase

Tags: python

My task:

Input format:
The first line contains one natural number
The second line contains the necessary phrase.

Output format:
NN lines of the form: I like "<phrase>"!

Here's what I got:

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input()) 
for i in range(a):
    print("I like", " ", "\"", b, "\"", "!", sep="")
```

But my reviewer did not accept this, what can be changed in the code or done in a completely different way?

Comment: That might be a question you take up with your reviewer, but just something that catches my eye, you should wrap `a` and `b` in a `try / except` like so, `try: a = int(input()); b = int(input()); except ValueError: print("Not ints!"); else: for i in range(a): ...`

Comment: `b = int(input())` - `b` is _most probaby_ `str`, and therefore this would raise `ValueError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I think removing the `sep` argument from the `print` because the test requires the phrase on different lines</strike> (for some reason i thought it was `end` )

Edit: As shmak and fen1x suggested the second arument is probably a string so using int will break it

```py
a = int(input())
b = str(input()) 
for i in range(a):
    print(f'I like "{b}"!')
```

Comment: `sep` in `print` tells how to separate arguments in single `print` call. `end` in `print` tells what should be appended to the end of the string - it is `\n` (or other OS-specific newline symbol) by default.

Comment: @fen1x ah right i am dumb 